# How to change a vertex coordinate using SetProperty

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I was trying to set (change) a vertex coordinate this way:

```
g = Graph@{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 4}
SetProperty[{g, 1}, VertexCoordinates -> {0.25, 1}]
```

But failed. At the same time this works nicely

```
SetProperty[{g, 1}, VertexLabels -> 1]
```

Both propeties are in this list

```
PropertyList[{g, 1}]
```

Could you explain what my mistake is? And how to change vertex coordinate using SetProperty?

Answer (score 5):

By default, the graph is laid out automatically.  No explicit vertex coordinates are stored.

If you decide to store vertex coordinates, you must do so for *all* vertices.  Currently, the built-in layout algorithms do not support fixing the position of only a subset of vertices.  Once explicit coordinates are set for all vertices, `SetProperty` works for changing only one at a time.

```
g = Graph@{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 4};
```

These work:

```
g2 = SetProperty[g, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]

g3 = SetProperty[g, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {0, 0}, 2 -> {0, 1}, 3 -> {1, 0}, 4 -> {1, 1}}]

g4 = Graph[g, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {0, 0}, 2 -> {0, 1}, 3 -> {1, 0}, 4 -> {1, 1}}]
```

This does not:

```
SetProperty[{g, 1}, VertexCoordinates -> {2, 2}]
```

This one does:

```
SetProperty[{g2, 1}, VertexCoordinates -> {2, 2}]
```

---

**Update**

If you want to keep the positions you currently see, and move a single vertex, I recommend

```
g = Graph@{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 4}
```

[image]

```
g = Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g]];
PropertyValue[{g, 1}, VertexCoordinates] = {0.25, 1}

g
```

[image]

This will modify the graph in-place.

Comment: Thank you. So, to change coordinates of a subset of vertices I have to do something like this coords = PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList[g] and then SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> ReplacePart[coords, 2 -> {1, 1}]]

Comment: @GregoryFridman You can do that, but I would do the following. First, `g = Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g]]` to set *explicit* (not automatic) coordinates for all vertices. Then you can use `SetProperty` to modify just one vertex in the same way as you tried in the question.